# Is this a valid example of a poset?

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, order-theory, congruences, sorting

I am trying to understand better the basic concepts of [partially ordered sets](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set), and tried my own examples by using modular-arithmetic. For this, I tried to define an algorithm to order integers, here is the idea, my question is after the example:

> 1- Def. set of positive integers
>   $S=\{s_0,s_1,s_2,s_3,..,s_n\}\ /\ S\in\Bbb N $. Repetition of elements
>   is possible, and $0$ is possible.
>
> 2- Move all $0's$ to a new list $S0$. They are not evaluated.
>
> 3- For every $s_i\ /\ i\in [0..n]$ element of $S-S0$ do as follows:
>
> 3.1- Def. $SL=\{s_0..s_{i}\}$ and $SR=\{s_{i+1}..,s_n\}$
>
> 3.1.1- For every $s_k \in SR$ calculate $m_k = s_k\ mod\ s_i$
>
> 3.1.2- Reorder $SR$ in increasing order according to $m_k$. If two or more elements have the same value, then keep the
>   original order between them (for that reason, if $s_i$ is $1$ then no
>   changes are applied to $SR$).
>
> 4- Move back the $0's$ to $S$: $S = S + S0$

E.g.

> $S=\{7,34,12,48,0,7\}$
>
> there is one $0$, so $S0=\{0\}$ and $S-S0=\{7,34,12,48,7\}$
>
> Loop in s_i:
>
> for the first element $7$, after sorting $S=\{7,7,12,34,48\}$
>
> for the second element, again $7$, so no changes happened $S=\{7,7,12,34,48\}$
>
> for the third element $12$, $S=\{7,7,12,48,34\}$
>
> we arrived to the element before the last element, $48$, so no more changes are possible.
>
> finally $S=\{7,7,12,48,34\}+\{0\}=\{7,7,12,48,34,0\}$

The point is: this algorithm would sort the data from left to right providing always for every $s_i$ the element of $S$ at the right of $s_i$ which is the closest number to a factor of $s_i$, so it is possible for instance to calculate the average distance of a generic element of the set to a generic factor of the set: $D_S = avg(s_{i+1} \ mod\ s_i)$. This might be useful to verify the randomness of a set of integers.

According to the Wiki definition: A poset consists of a set together with a binary relation that indicates that, for certain pairs of elements in the set, one of the elements precedes the other. Such a relation is called a partial order to reflect the fact that not every pair of elements need be related: for some pairs, it may be that neither element precedes the other in the poset.

And applied to the sample $S=\{7,7,12,48,34\}$ above:

1. Partial order of $s_2$: $s_2 \le s_{2+k}$ because

$(s_2\ mod\ s_1) \le (s_3\ mod s_1)$ and

$(s_2\ mod\ s_1) \le (s_4\ mod s_1)$ and

$(s_2\ mod\ s_1) \le (s_5\ mod s_1)$.

2. Partial order of $s_3$: $s_3 \le s_{3+k}$ because

$(s_3\ mod\ s_2) \le (s_4\ mod s_2)$ and

$(s_3\ mod\ s_2) \le (s_5\ mod s_2)$.

3. Partial order of $s_4$: $s_4 \le s_{4+k}$ because

$(s_4\ mod\ s_3) \le (s_5\ mod s_3)$.

> Would the generated set be a valid example of a poset?

Comment: You sort $SR$ such that they are in increasing order of remainder module $s_i$, right? and you will sort $S - S_0$ in the very beginning such that all elements are in increasing order of values?

Comment: @echo yes SR gets ordered in increasing order of remainder module $s_i$ by the previous element to SR. But $S-S_0$ in the very beginning is unordered. In the sample you can see  that $S-S_0$ is unordered, just removed the $0's$, and then from that point, apply the algorithm first taking the first element of the set and ordering the rest of the set with the remainder mod the first element, so the set is reordered. Then take the second element and do the same up to the end of the set (except the first one), then after reordering, take the third and make again the algorithm up to the end, etc.

Comment: Make sense. Let $S'$ be the resulting set. How you define the relation $\leq$ between elements? Is the relation $s_i \leq s_j$ iff $i \leq j$?

Comment: Maybe my statement is a little misleading. I mean to prove that the generated set is a poset, you must define a binary relation on it. So what is the relation?

Comment: I don't think that's true. Let $S = \{3, 4, 7, 8\}$. After your procedure, it becomes $S = \{3, 4, 8, 7\}$. Note that $8 \text{ mod } 3 = 2$ and $7 \text{ mod } 3 = 1$. So, in general, $(s_i \text{ mod } s_{i-t}) \leq (s_{i+k}\text{ mod }s_{i-t})$ is not true.

Comment: @echo you are right, thinking about it, the only truth would be that $s_{i+1}$ is  $\forall k \ge i+1$ the element with the smallest possible congruence value of $s_k\ mod\ s_i$, so in that way $s_{i+1}$ is smaller (or equal to some other element to the right side like in your sample in worst of cases) than the rest of the set to its right side when compared to $\pmod {s_i}$. Does it make sense?

Comment: I know about this. But I feel confused since in your last comment, you said "$\forall k, t$, we have $(s_i \text{ mod } s_{i-t}) \leq (s_{i+k}\text{ mod }s_{i-t})$, so always $s_i \leq s_{i+k}$."

Comment: So for different $s_i$, there will be a binary relation on $\{s_{i+1}, \cdots, s_n\}$, right?

Comment: But how you define the relation on the generated set? Can you explain using $\{7, 7, 12, 48, 34\}$ in your question as an example? (by listing all pairs satisfying the relation) It seems that you've misunderstood the concept of POSET.

Comment: @echo added the partial order relationships as I understood them. If that does not work, then I will need to review the theory and it would not be a good sample of poset. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if it is not what you intent for.

Let $S = \{7, 7, 14, 7\}$. After your procedure, $S$ remains the same. We have
$$
s_2 = 7 \leq s_3 = 14
$$
and
$$
s_3 = 14 \leq s_4 = 7
$$
implying $7 \leq 14$ and $14 \leq 7$ but $14 \neq 7$, thus violate the antisymmetry of a poset.

Comment: clearly I need to review the theory, until now I did not take into account the antisymmetry of a poset. Thank you!